# Задержка при ошибке в setInterval

Tags: javascript

Нужно сделать задержку в запросе  setInterval

```
var iid = null;
iid = setInterval(doSomething, 1000);

function doSomething() {
    var req; // отправить 

    if (req) { // Проверка на ошибку
        console.log(req);
        idx++;
    } else { // Ошибка
        // Нужно сделать задержку в 500мс
        console.log("Error");
    }

    if (idx == 20) { // конец цикла
        clearInterval(iid);
    }
}
```

Пробовал `setTimeout(function() {}, 500);`

Comment: Запускайте еще один таймер. Ставьте признак запуска и через время стирайте. Прямые способы задержки хоть и предлагаются, но работают не очень...

Comment: @DNS еще один setInterval ?

Comment: Да, еще один. (`timeOut`) Перед включением ставьте `delay=true` На функционал ставьте проверку `if(!delay)...` по прошествию времени сбрасывайте признак.

Comment: @DNS не понял как "по прошествию времени сбрасывайте признак"

Comment: `delay = true; setTimeout(function(){delay=false;},500)`

Comment: странное поведении происходит... код останавливается, а запросы на сервер проходят.

Comment: Задержать все - не получится. Это ж события, они приходят - обработчики включаются. Все ведь и не надо задерживать - гифки должны анимироваться, мышь двигаться и т.п. Но там, где нужна задержка, перед кодом надо поставить `if(!delay)`